# On keycloak's update password screen, is it possible to show all password requirements before submitting

Tags: keycloak

We are using Keycloak as authentication mechanism and also to manage user credentials (as resetting passwords)

When changing passwords, passwords requirements (at least 1 upper case, at least 1 lower case, at least 1 special char, etc) are only shown after submitted and individually.

Which is a little bit annoying for the user.

The question then is if it is possible **to show all password requirements together**? And/or if it is possible to show all requirements as soon the page is loaded and before submitting a password?

This is the template user for that page:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/account/password.ftl

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code, it seems that it is not possible to do this straight from Keycloak.

Although, there is the project [Keycloakify](https://docs.keycloakify.dev/) that provides support for real-time input validation, amongst some additional customization options.